# Use selenium to download multiple pdfs from a list of urls

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I have the below code but it doesn't seem to download into my folder. I am able to pull out a list of url that contains the PDF but I am unable to make my code that downloads the PDF work.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
executable_path=os.path.join(GenericMethods.get_full_path_to_folder('drivers'), "chromedriver.exe"),
chrome_options=chrome_options)
download_dir = "D:\VIX\FOMC_Minutes"
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
      'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

years = ['1983', '1982', '1981', '1980', '1979', '1978', '1977', '1976', '1975', '1974',
     '1973', '1972', '1971', '1970', '1969', '1968', '1967', '1966', '1965', '1964',
     '1963', '1962', '1961', '1960']

driver.get(f'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
pdf_links=[]
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name('list-search.form-control.input-sm')
for y in years:

for m in months:
    print (m + "-" + y)
    search.clear()
    search.send_keys(y)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '" + y + "')]/parent::a")))
    xpath = "//span[contains(., '" + m + "') and contains(., '" + y + "')]/parent::a"
    elinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    if len(elinks)>0:
        print(elinks[0].get_attribute('href'))
        pdf_links.append(elinks[0].get_attribute('href'))

driver.quit()
print(pdf_links)

for url in pdf_links:
page = driver.get(url)
elinks = page.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='.pdf']")
for elink in elinks:
download = driver.find_element_by_link_text(elink)
download.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make little tweak to your script and use wget rather standard download. By that way the download will be easy and faster.

make sure to add this import.

```
import wget
```

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
pdf_links=[]

for y in years:

    for m in months:
        driver.get(f'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677')
        search = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "list-search.form-control.input-sm")))
        search.clear()
        search.send_keys(y)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '" + y + "')]/parent::a")))
        xpath = "//span[contains(., '" + m + "') and contains(., '" + y + "')]/parent::a"
        elinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
        if len(elinks)>0:
            driver.get(elinks[0].get_attribute('href'))
            # linkEle = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block']")))
            linkEle = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block']")
            if len(linkEle) >0:
                wget.download(linkEle[0].get_attribute('href'), m + "_" + y + ".pdf")
                # if you want to download to any specific directory then append the dir path as shown below.
                wget.download(linkEle[0].get_attribute('href'), dir_path + "/" + m + "_" + y + ".pdf")
driver.quit()
```